# Java FloatBuffer size error OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, light, floatbuffer

working with LWJGL's implementation of OpenGL, and trying to work with the lighting functions.  This requires the creation of FloatBuffers to pass to OpenGL.  Relevant code follows:

```
GL11.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

float[] ambientLight={(float).3,(float).5,(float).8,1};
FloatBuffer ambientLightB = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
ambientLightB.put(ambientLight);

float[] diffuseLight={(float).25,(float).25,(float).25,1};
FloatBuffer diffuseLightB = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
diffuseLightB.put(diffuseLight);

float[] lightPosition={0,0,1,1};
FloatBuffer lightPositionB = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
lightPositionB.put(lightPosition);

float[] matAmbient={1,1,1,1};
FloatBuffer matAmbientB = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
matAmbientB.put(matAmbient);

float[] matDiff={1,1,1,1};
FloatBuffer matDiffB = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
matDiffB.put(matDiff);

GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
GL11.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT,GL11.GL_AMBIENT,matAmbientB);
GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE,matDiffB);
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0,GL11.GL_AMBIENT,ambientLightB);
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0,GL11.GL_DIFFUSE,diffuseLightB);
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0,GL11.GL_POSITION,lightPositionB);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);
```

The first call I make to glMaterial gives the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 0, must be at least 4. Because at most 4 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 4 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, seems to be a problem in the creation of the FloatBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up requiring another function call specific to LWJGL (BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer), as well as the flip() method.  The following correctly initialized the buffer

```
float[] matAmbient={1,1,1,1};
FloatBuffer matAmbientB = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
matAmbientB.put(matAmbient);
matAmbientB.flip();
```

Answer (score 1):

Flip() the buffer after the put(), or use FloatBuffer.wrap(), which would also save you some lines of code. Or maybe it needs *another* 4 slots, so allocate 8 elements.

Comment: I don't see any flip() method in the java documentation of the class... Wrap doesn't work, that gives me an error saying I need a direct Buffer... Shouldn't need 8 buffers, the equivalent function call in C takes a size 4 array

Comment: Flip was in the super class, gave the same direct buffer error

Comment: @sol_var (1) Buffer.flip() does exist, look again. It is inherited. (2) If you really need a direct buffer, `allocate()` shouldn't work either, you would have to use `allocateDirect()`. Something wrong here. (3) There is no `C` equivalent of `FloatBuffer`. I think you're going to have to look again at the documentation for the package you're using.

Comment: EJP, thank you for your information, it was very helpful.  Just to clarify, by C equivalent, I meant the equivalent of the function call, not the equivalent of the FloatBuffer.  In C the function glMaterialfv would be called instead for the exact same effect, and its third parameter is a pointer to a float array of size four instead of a FloatBuffer of size 4.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using FloatBuffers with LWJGL is so native code can use there buffers directly, in order for this to work correctly they should be used like so,

```
//Create a directly allocated buffer in bytes (16 = 4 Floats * size of float in bytes)
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer fb = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
fb.put(...);
fb.rewind(); //Moves the internal buffer pointer back to the start for the next thing to read from it
```

The ByteOrder.nativeOrder() will ensure that whether your system uses big or little endian it will be transferred correctly from java to native code. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

The LWJGL buffer util likely does this for you